# Filter fields reset on table redraw

Tags: yadcf

Above the datatable, of documents, I have a full text search  input field. When I get the results (resultDocuments) I put them in using:

`table.clear().rows.add(resultDocuments).draw();`

While the filtering **is** still happening, the filter fields all go blank. How do I make the keep their values?

Thank you.

Comment: strange, please provide a link to a test page showing this issue

Comment: @Daniel Weirdly, this isn't happening today. Filter fields keeps their values. I can't say for certain that this bug wasn't caused by me. Will keep an eye on it.